# How to distinguish wizards in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

We have an Eclipse IDE application on 3.x that uses various newWizards to allow the user to create different files. Although these files differ slightly contentwise, the structure of the wizards is quite similar.

Thus, a sound object-oriented approach would be to instantiate different wizards from the same class and initialize them with different data.

**Problem:**

To decide what wizard needs which data we need a way to distinguish the different already instantiated wizards (e.g during the call to the init method of the wizard).

Is there any way to do so? It would e.g. help if somebody knows a way to get the wizard's id defined in the extension point from within the instantiated wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wizard implements [`IExecutableExtension`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIExecutableExtension.html), it will be passed the configuration element that represents the extension for which it is created.

You can also use *extension factories* in that you specify a type that implements [`IExecutableExtensionFactory`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIExecutableExtensionFactory.html).

The interface allows you to control how the instances provided to extension-points (wizards in your case) are created.

Extension example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.wizards">
<newWizard  
  name="..."  
  class="com.example.WizardFactory"> 
</newWizard>
```

Note that the extension factory may also implement `IExecutableExtension` to gain access to extension attributes before creating the extension's executable class.

Comment: Thank a ton. that was exactly what I was looking for